# Non-bootable windows install

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, windows-installation

I have recently tried to install windows 11 by flashing a .iso file to a 10 gigabyte system partition. The mounting of the disk and extraction goes perfectly, and I have marked the partition as bootable in Gparted, but it appears with a message stating that the disk is not bootable. I have looked around for a fix, have tried ntfs and fat32 partitions, and have not found anything. Can someone help me out?

Note: I am on peppermint OS, so anything that will work on there will do.

Comment: Why not just put the Windows 11 ISO on a USB Key. Run Setup.exe from the USB key and let Windows make its own partitions.

Comment: Also, you most likely need to install Windows 10 / 11 first and then your other system after Windows is working.

Comment: As @John states. installing Windows 11 would likely mess up Peppermint. *First* delete all partitions, then use Windows 11 **installation media**, preferably created at https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11 to partition drive and install Windows, *then* create free space and install 2nd OS. Or just run Windows or Peppermint in a VM.

Comment: @Xenan - Can you [edit] your question to indicate what tool you used to flash the ISO to the partition? Understanding what you did in detail will help identify why what you did isn’t working

Answer (score -3):

Boot from the .iso (via USB or mounted iso in virtual machine) and then if you clear the whole disk, Windows setup will take care of creating the correct bootable partitions for you.

You may want to look for UEFI/legacy settings in bios and make sure to boot with proper setting. Windows 11 requires:

- TPM 2.0
- UEFI
- 4GB RAM
- 64GB storage

If you have smaller disk there may be problem. It can work for a while, but after updates and installation of programs 64GB is usually too small. It is probably better to run it in a virtual machine where you can expand disk more easily instead of trying to dual boot with very small OS disk.

See also here for full information:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-system-requirements-86c11283-ea52-4782-9efd-7674389a7ba3

For Linux and Windows 11 dual boot, UEFI and GPT disk may be easiest. Read more here :
https://wiki.debian.org/DualBoot/Windows

In case you need to bypass Windows 11 TPM, RAM, secure boot checks in test system there are registry keys to do this:
https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/bypass-windows-11-tpm-requirement